# How to find a minimum and maximum value in a word array in MIPS assembly

Tags: arrays, max, mips, min

I have been having some difficulty getting my program to work. I am new to MIPS assembly and was wondering how to find the maximum and minimum values in a .word array. I keep getting a minimum of 16 and a maximum of 0 when I compile. This is my code so far:

```
# Write MIPS that searches an array of numbers for the largest and smallest element.
# The directive .word is used to set up an array of 20 4-byte words
# in the data section

# t1 -- contains count of elements
# t2 -- contains min value
# t3 -- contains max value
# t4 -- each word from array in turn

# data segment

.data  

anArray: .word 3, 4, 2, 6, 223, 345, 121, 92, 99, 14, 7, 76, 67, 49, 56, 43, 7, 81, 21, 31
count: .word 20
Thursday: .asciiz "Today is Thursday Feb 09, 2017"
result1: .asciiz "\n\n\nThe Minimum Value is = "
result2: .asciiz "\n\n\nThe Maximum Value is = "

# text segment

.text 
.globl main
 main:

    #System Call to print Thursday String 
la $a0, Thursday
li $v0, 4
syscall 

    #System Call to print Minimum Value String 
la $a0, result1
li $v0, 4
syscall

la $t4, anArray
li $t1, 0

    #System Call to print Minimum Value
Loop:
lb $t0, 0($t4)
blt $t0, $t2, anArrayEnd
addi $t1, $t1, 1
addi $t4, $t4, 1
j Loop
anArrayEnd:

move $a0, $t1
li $v0, 1
syscall

    #System Call to print Maximum Value String
la $a0, result2
li $v0, 4
syscall

la $t4, anArray
li $t1, 0

    #System Call to print Maximum Value

Loop1:
lb $t0, 0($t4)
bgt $t0, $t3, anArrayEnd1
addi $t1, $t1, 1
addi $t4, $t4, 1
j Loop1
anArrayEnd1:

move $a0, $t1
li $v0, 1
syscall

    #System Call to exit
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Comment: A word is 4 bytes, not 1. If correcting that doesn't solve the problem, use the debugging features in the simulator to find why the wrong values are printed.

Comment: Thank you @Michael I am a little new to this, so in order for me to change the word to 4 bytes would I  change lb to lw in the lines light after the loops start?

Comment: That, and the address increments need to be 4 instead of 1.

Comment: Okay so the loop would look like:                                                         Loop:
lw $t0, 0($t4)
blt $t0, $t2, anArrayEnd
addi $t1, $t1, 4
addi $t4, $t4, 4
j Loop
anArrayEnd: